# JavaFX alternatives as Java and Linux mind coders?

Tags: java, linux, oracle, user-interface, javafx

What are the Linux user alternatives for JavaFX powered by Oracle? (without switching to Mac/Windows platform).

Comment: this question should be asked on askubuntu.com. Isn't?

Comment: JavaFX (old version) that i wrote does not work with new JavaFX. So deciding i have to look alternatives of Oracle products.

Comment: What is the problem with new JavaFX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Flash, [Flex](http://flex.org/)
- Microsoft Silverlight ([Moonlight](http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight) port)

Comment: Is there nothing native for Linux?

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean by "native" in this case